# Opengl es on android problem with object opsition on projection matrix

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

I trying to display object with opengl es 3. Everything works till i trying to set camera view. When I multiply my vPMatrix with camera matrix and projection matrix object just disapears.

```
            float[] projectionMatrix = new float[16];
            float[] vPMatrix = new float[16];
            float[] camera = new float[16];
            Matrix.frustumM(
                    projectionMatrix,
                    0,
                    -1,
                    1,
                    -1,
                    1,
                    3,
                    7
            );

            Matrix.setLookAtM(
                    camera
                    , 0
                    //where i am
                    , 0f
                    , 0f
                    , 1f
                    //what i looking for
                    , 0f
                    , 0f
                    , -1f
                    //where is top
                    , 0f
                    , 1f
                    , 0f
            );


            Matrix.multiplyMM(
                    vPMatrix,
                    0,
                    projectionMatrix,
                    0,
                    camera,
                    0
            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moste likely the geometry is clipped by the near plane of the [Viewing frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum). Note, if the geometry is not between the near and far plane, the geoemtry is clipped.

[image]

You specified a distance to the near plane of 3 and a distance to the far plane of 7 when setting the perspective projection:

> ```java
> Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 3, 7);
> ```

But the distance of the point of view to the the center fot the worlds is just 1:

> ```java
> Matrix.setLookAtM(camera, 0, 0f, 0f, 1f, ...);
> ```

---

You have 2 options. Either change the point of view:

```java
Matrix.setLookAtM(camera, 0, 0f, 0f, 5f, ...);
```

Or change the near and far plane. For instance:

```java
Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0.1, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that bug by setting camera as below:

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(
                    camera
                    , 0
                    //where i am
                    , 0f
                    , 0f
                    , 5f
                    //what i looking for
                    , 0f
                    , 0f
                    , 0f
                    //where is top
                    , 0f
                    , 1f
                    , 0f
            );
```

but i dont understand why old version was bad (what i looking for z). If enyone can explain me this then please post youre answer.